# Primefaces dataTable filter search By not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 In my project I use dataTable and filter.In filter textbox to I enter value it will return no records found .It only show when first letter  value given data to showing result (i.e) In my table name column value has **Raja,Suresh,kathir**. In userName column filter textbox value to First letter name r given to only shown raja  result, Mid letter word of r result is not shown. When type **t** it result not shown.
My doubt is it text letter type starting letter based to only shown result

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="userWidget"   
         id="userTable" value="#{ctrbean.list}" var="p" filteredValue="#{ctrbean.list}">

    :column   id="r" headerText="ID" 
    filterBy="#{p.userName}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{p.userName}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Note:I use rowkey attribute also but not working.Why it only shown based on starting letter only

Comment: did my answer help? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

add `filterMatchMode="contains"` to your column as shown here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml